# Wordpress shows a live URL even if this doesn't exist, symbols between the slang words give a live page instead of 404 error

Tags: wordpress

It's a problem that I just noticed.
If I add to any WordPress site any symbols or more hyphens where the hyphen is in the URL I don't get a 404 error as it should but a working page under a new messy URL.
Example: https://www.celebritycruises.com/blog/corfu----!!!!@@!-beaches shows the same content as: https://www.celebritycruises.com/blog/corfu-beaches, and so on.
To my opinion, this is horrible, not duplicated content but worse.
This is present on every single WordPress site, I wonder why this happens and almost seems undetected!
Any solution? This example is not my site but it happens to all my sites too.

Comment: I noticed this even in Forbes site

Comment: I think this is done on purpose bu Wordpress. If it hits a 404 page it executes the function 'redirect_guess_404_permalink'.